# How to remove main activities buttons from the fragment with the codes in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

How to remove main activities buttons from the fragment with the codes in android?

There are a few buttons in `activity_main.xml`. I want to access and remove a button from the fragment class. Is this posssible and how?

**main_activ.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/paper"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/butBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="60.0dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text=".."
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="16.0sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/butMain"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60.0dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="..."
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="16.0sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/butNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60.0dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text=".."
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:textSize="16.0sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                    android:textStyle="bold" /> 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My fragment**

```
public class Frag_Menu extends Fragment  {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_menu, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.butBack).getParent();
        if(null!=layout) 
            layout.removeView(layout);
    };

    public static android.support.v4.app.Fragment newInstance(String string) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getActivity().findViewById()` to get your Button from the fragment class in `onActivityCreated()`.

```
View button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.butBack);
if (button != null && button.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup)button.getParent()).removeView(button);
}
```

Comment: What error? Post your code and your xml and the error.

Comment: see my updated code. you can't have the layout remove itself -- you need to have the layout remove the button.

Comment: You are right. but I didnt solve the problem ,I will post you source  codes

Comment: with your help, I solved my problem,  
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState) must be the first statement for onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) for fragments. Now It works. Thank you very much

Comment: Not vote up. Just accept the answer. You asked the question, so only you can accept the correct answer. Click the check mark on left under the vote arrows.

Comment: Hi mikejonesguy, I need help, I know it is very easy for you. I posted new question The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393999/how-to-use-simply-adapterviewpager-getregisteredfragmentnumber can you help me? I gave full source It halfly runs